# uncaught promise rejection: failed to eval source for module 'nanoid': node_modules/nanoid/index.cjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-realm

I'm trying to use nanoid (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid/v/2.1.2)

```js
exports = async function(){
  const nanoid = require("nanoid");
  const uid = nanoid(10);
}
```

From within MongoDB realm runtime, but it throws:

```
uncaught promise rejection: failed to eval source for module 'nanoid': node_modules/nanoid/index.cjs: Line 9:7 Unexpected identifier (and 16 more errors)
```

And this is about all the error I can see from the Realm Dashboard.

What could be missing?

Comment: You must take const nanoid = require("nanoid") out of the function and use asinc/await syntax,promise is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me:

- Install a lower version nanoid

```sh
npm i nanoid@2.1.2
```

Then upload the package to MongoDB Realm functions through the dashboard.